# Parse a file with a regexp and return first match

Tags: input, expl3, latex3, parsing

I need to write a command that searches a file for a string that matches a certain regexp, and inserts that string. I know how to parse a string of text using a regex with

```
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycom #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { THE-REGEXP } { THE-REPLACEMENT } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but I don't know how I can use it to parse the contents of a file. I tried replacing `{#1}` with `{\input{#1}}`, but it didn't work (the `\input` was simply considered part of the string).

Comment: Take a look at the `catchfile` package to allow you to read an entire file to a macro, or iterate over the file line-by-line with `\ior_map_inline:Nn` (experimental function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no facility, at the moment, for storing into a token list the contents of a file, but you can still use the `catchfile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycom #1
  {
    \CatchFileDef \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { xrep } { foo } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mycom{xrep}
```

**Update**

In the revision dated 2014-06-25, the functionality has been added to `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycom}{m}
 {
  \malabarba_mycom:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_malabarba_mycom_content_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \malabarba_mycom:n #1
  {
   \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_malabarba_mycom_content_tl {} {#1}
   \regex_replace_all:nnN { xrep } { foo } \l_malabarba_mycom_content_tl
   \tl_use:N \l_malabarba_mycom_content_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mycom{xrep}
```

Note that there's a difference between `\CatchFileDef` and `\tl_set_from_file:Nnn`: in the former command the *trailing* argument contains setup instructions to be performed (locally) before loading the file, in the latter these setup tokens should go in the second argument

```
\CatchFileDef<command name>{<filename>}{<setup>}

\tl_set_from_file:Nnn <tl variable> { <setup> } { <filename> }
```

The analog of `\CatchFileEdef` is called

```
\tl_set_from_file_x:Nnn
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Any chance I might get LaTeX to interpret the output? =) (instead of just displaying it verbatim)

Comment: @BruceConnor I get what's expected. Probably what you get wrong depends on the "replacement" regex you're using.

Comment: What do you mea by that? The regexp does output what I expect it to (`{\bf Test}` for example). The problem is that this output does't get iterpreted by LaTeX (so my pdf would contain a literal `{\bf Test}` istead of a **`Test`**). Is that not the expected behaviour?

Comment: @BruceConnor If the search regex is something like `([^\*]*?)\*\*` and the replacement regex is ``\c{textbf}\cB\{\1\cE\}`` I get that `**Test**` is replaced by `\textbf{Test}` and interpreted correctly.

Comment: If I copy/paste your answer's preamble to a new document, replace xrep with `.*` and foo with `\c{textbf}\cB\{ Hi \cE\}`, create a file in the same folder cotaining `**TEST**`, and call `\mycom{filename}` inside begin/end{document} I get the bizarre: `c–textbf ̋cB–HicE ̋c–textbf ̋cB–HicE ̋`

Comment: I guess that probably means I've hit a bug. =/

Comment: This bizarre result actually only hapenned in the new document. If I insert this code into my existent document I just get `c{textbf}cB{HicE}c{textbf}cB{HicE}`, which basically means it's not getting interpreted right (though I have no idea why they behave different).

Comment: @BruceConnor You probably have an outdated version of `l3regex`; mine is `l3regex.dtx 3488 2012-03-03 19:49:03Z`

Comment: @BruceConnor: It would be very helpful if you can update `l3regex` and check again.  If the problem persists, please let me know (I wrote `l3regex`).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'll try that next week (how do I check my current version?). For now I have a thesis to defend, so I'm in a bit of a hurry. =)

Comment: @BruceConnor good luck for your defense.  Can you compile the document in egreg's answer, with `xrep` replaced by `.*` and `foo` replaced by `\c{textbf}\cB\{ Hi \cE\}`?  You'd probably need to add an `\begin{document}...\end{document}` too.  To get the file versions you can add `\listfiles` at the very start of your document: the info appears at the end of hte log file.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Ok. My l3regex was indeed outdated (from about 8 months ago). I've updated it and the problem was solved.