# Input - Include part of file based on content

Tags: input

I have a chatlog file (`chat.tex)`, and would like to include different parts of it in different parts of my document.

I can extract the relevant parts I want using regular expressions, or string indexing, for example:

chat.tex

```tex
% 2021-12-30 00:00:00
First text of the day

% 2021-12-30 00:00:01
Second text of the day

% 2021-12-30 00:00:02
Third text of the day

% 2021-12-30 00:00:03
Fourth text of the day
```

I would like to include in one part of the document all text between `% 2021-12-30 00:00:01` and `% 2021-12-30 00:00:03`:

```tex
Second text of the day

% 2021-12-30 00:00:02
Third text of the day
```

Ideally, to prevent multiple read requests to the `chat.tex` file, its content should be stored as a variable, and one would get the text from that variable.

Code if this was python:

```
chat = open("chat.tex", "r").read()
def extract(start, end):
  return chat[chat.index(start):chat.index(end)]

extract('% 2021-12-30 00:00:01', '% 2021-12-30 00:00:03')
```

(This might be partially a duplicate of [Parse a file with a regexp and return first match](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53204/parse-a-file-with-a-regexp-and-return-first-match) - but I do not understand the answer, and think it might be very outdated, and costly in my scenario. I also do not specifically intend to include a file based on line numbers [\input only part of file, without losing SyncTeX support?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438075/input-only-part-of-file-without-losing-synctex-support))

Comment: Simplest way would be to use LuaTeX or PythonTeX and implement it in Lua/Python respectively.

Comment: To understand the answer instead, read interface3 documentation and learn from there. Warning: TeX is highly nontrivial (even expl3), just use Lua/Python instead.

Comment: Thanks @user202729, unfortunately, `pythontex` does not work on overleaf due to security reasons. I'll attempt this with `luatex`

Comment: Seems like `directlua` and `luacode` are undefined control sequences in overleaf as well

Comment: Need to configure overleaf a bit. E.g.[luatex - How to set Overleaf to compile with `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291354/how-to-set-overleaf-to-compile-with-lualatex-shell-escape-file) (still, even if you can already program in e.g. Python, it's easier to compile locally than learn TeX-the-programming-language.)

Comment: Actually overleaf already have guide to change compiler https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler . (from  [luatex - Error message from including luacode package in Overleaf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557778/error-message-from-including-luacode-package-in-overleaf)  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user202729 the solution is as follows:

1. Change the tex engine to `lualatex`, as this solution depends on some lua code.
2. Create a lua function to read the file and look for the lines:

```lua
-- chat.lua

local f = assert(io.open("chat.tex", "r"))
local chat_file = f:read("*all")
f:close()

function readchat(starts, ends)
  i1 = string.find(chat_file, starts) + string.len(starts)
  i2 = string.find(chat_file, ends) - 2

  sub_content = string.sub(chat_file, i1, i2)

  --- tex.print treats the string as one line...  
  for line in string.gmatch(sub_content,"[^\r\n]*") do
    tex.print(line)
  end
end
```

3. Create a latex alias to that function

```tex
\newcommand{\readchat}[2]{\directlua{readchat(#1, #2)}}
```

4. Include the `lua` file in the beginning of the document

```tex
\directlua{dofile("chat.lua")}
```

5. Search for a match

```tex
\readchat{"7/1/21T18:11:46"}{"7/2/21T09:44:20"}
```